# Satzstellung mit zu

Tags: sentence-structure, subordinate-clause

Welche Wortstellung ist richtig?

Du weißt, dass ich anfangen zu spielen will - vs. - Du weißt, dass ich zu spielen anfangen will

Du weißt, dass er zu spielen angefangen hat - vs. - Du weißt, dass er angefangen hat, zu spielen

Wenn du jetzt zu spielen beginnst, wirst du früher zu spielen enden - vs. - Wenn du jetzt beginnst, zu spielen, wirst du früher enden, zu spielen

Answer (score 4):

*zu* + Infinitiv verhält sich, was die Wortstellung betrifft, nicht wie ein Bestandteil des Verbs, sondern wie ein Präpositionalbobjekt.

Bei Verbendstellung kann es daher dem mehrteiligen Verb vorangestellt sein oder ihnen nachfolgen:

> Du weißt, dass ich anfangen will zu spielen.

> Du weißt, dass ich zu spielen anfangen will.

Es kann aber nicht zwischen die Verbteile treten. Daher ist *Du weißt, dass ich anfangen zu spielen will* inkorrekt.

Bei Sätzen mit Verbklammer kann *zu spielen* innerhalb der Verbklammer platziert sein oder ausgeklammert werden:

> Wenn du jetzt zu spielen beginnst, wirst du früher zu spielen aufhören.

> Wenn du jetzt beginnst, zu spielen, wirst du früher aufhören, zu spielen.

Beides ist korrekt. Statt *enden* muss aber *aufhören* verwendet werden, weil *enden* nicht mit *zu* + Infinitiv verwendet werden kann.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked in German I'll also answer in German.

Im ersten Satz `Du weißt, dass ich anfangen zu spielen will` bzw. `Du weißt, dass ich zu spielen anfangen will` hätte ich gesagt, dass die zweite Version, nämlich `Du weißt, dass ich zu spielen anfangen will`. Allerdings würde ich den Satzbau vereinfachen, ich würde daraus `Du weißt, dass ich anfangen will zu spielen` machen.

Der zweite Satz ist schon etwas schwieriger, ich würde aber trotzdem bei der zweiten Version bleiben, nämlich `Du weißt, dass er angefangen hat, zu spielen`.

Im dritten Satz hätte ich gesagt, dass beide richtig sind, da der Satzbau aber sehr kompliziert ist, kann ich das nicht 100% sagen. Ich hätte den Satzbau vereinfacht, in dem ich gesagt hätte: `Wenn du jetzt beginnst zu spielen, wirst du früher damit aufhören`. So ist der Satz auf die Schnelle leichter zu verstehen.

If you wanted an answer in english, let me know